# Upload assets with Octokit

Tags: github-api, octokit

I'm reading the docs at https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/releases#upload-a-release-asset but I don't see the page describing how to actually upload the asset?

All I can see is the page saying I should upload as binary but do I actually use octokit to upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use Octokit, I recommend you to try `@octokit/rest.js`. This API Client SDK will help you bypass most of the headaches when interacting with GitHub's API.

Checking [their docs](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#repos-upload-release-asset) you can find the equivalent to doing `octokit.request('POST /repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases/{release_id}/assets', ...)`:

```js
octokit.rest.repos.uploadReleaseAsset({
  owner,
  repo,
  release_id,
  name,
  data,
});
```

---

Also, in github.com/@octokit/rest.js, I found a example in /tests which probably will be useful to you as guidance: [@octokit/rest.js -> release-assets.test.ts](https://github.com/octokit/rest.js/blob/a2f69ec4b91175b6057c4693cf5e07ae5f86152f/test/scenarios/release-assets.test.ts#L28-L38):

```js
octokit.request({
          method: "POST",
          url: result.data.upload_url,
          headers: {
            "content-type": "text/plain",
          },
          data: "Hello, world!\n",
          name: "test-upload.txt",
          label: "test",
        });
      })
```

Comment: Has somebody succeeded uploading using the new OctoKit which was released here: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/assets?apiVersion=2022-11-28#upload-a-release-asset? I am mostly interested in the JS way of doing it.